# making report in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, collections

i'm making report by month i need to get product how many it was sold this month with quantity
My Code Returning all products but how i sum the same product so in example

```
{
  product_id: 1,
  qty: 2,
  line_total: 120,
  created_at: "2020-07-30T12:06:04.000000Z"
},
{
  product_id: 1,
  qty: 2,
  line_total: 120,
  created_at: "2020-07-30T12:06:04.000000Z"
},
```

i need to return it like this

```
{
  product_id: 1,
  qty: 4,
  line_total: 240,
  created_at: "2020-07-30T12:06:04.000000Z"
}
```

My code

```
    
    $product_orders =  \App\OrderProduct::select('product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')
        ->orderBy('created_at')->get();
    $product_orders->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
      return $item->created_at->format('m');
    });
    return $product_orders;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code... Hope it works

Use DB;

```
$products= OrderProduct::select(
                DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month'),
                DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year'),
                DB::raw('DAY(created_at) as day'),DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line') , 'product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')->groupBy('year', 'month','day')->get();
```

Comment: If you want to sum qty then you can give quantity like line total

Comment: thanks it worked but how i get it every year month day

Comment: i already did it with qty  can i goup them by month or day so the sum work with every month products or every  year

Comment: check the answer

Comment: thanks a lot but this wasn't what i mean i need 3 functions for day year month 
in first i will get total of products in every day next in every month and last in every year you already answerd my question should i do this in othe question or thread ?

Comment: i think you should ask a new question with what you actually want like your expected result, your current result etc so that a user can easily understand what you hvae and what you want

Comment: you can give me your thread link so that if i able to help you, i can

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63565089/making-report-in-laravel-by-day-month-year