# making report in laravel By Day Month Year

Tags: php, laravel

My Code Sum Products and quantity and price but i need 3 functions for day year month in first i will get total of products in every day next in every month and last in every year

the Code

```
$product_orders = \App\OrderProduct::select(DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line'),
DB::raw('sum(qty) as qty') , 'product_id','line_total','created_at')->
orderBy('created_at')->groupBy('product_id')->get();
```

DB

```
id , prdouct_id ,order_id, qty ,unit_total , line_total , created_at , updated_at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
##for grouping you can use it like these

public function day(){
$products= OrderProduct::select(
                DB::raw('DAY(created_at) as day'),DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line') , 'product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')->groupBy('day','product_id')->get();
}
public function month(){
$products= OrderProduct::select(
                DB::raw('MONTHNAME(created_at) as month'),
                DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line') , 'product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')->groupBy('month','product_id')->get();
}
public function year(){
$products= OrderProduct::select(
                DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year'),
               DB::raw('sum(line_total) as total_line') , 'product_id','qty','line_total','created_at')->groupBy('year','product_id')->get();
}
```

try this and let me know what happened

Comment: there is products not returning example in year just 2 products returned can you check it again please

Comment: can you post you database table so that i can ensure... i think the answer is ok

Comment: i mean with data .... I want to show all the rows...why data is not displayed

Comment: solved it By Adding rpdocut_id with every group please update your answer

Comment: haapy to know that you helped by my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$Rspatients = DB::table('reports')
->select(
    DB::raw("day(created_at) as day"),
    DB::raw("Count(*) as total_patients"))

->orderBy("created_at")
->groupBy(DB::raw("day(created_at)"))
->get();


$result_patients[] = ['day','Patients'];
foreach ($Rspatients as $key => $value) {
$result_patients[++$key] = [$value->day,$value->total_patients];
}
```

then you can pass it to your view like this:

```
return 
view('Dashboard.index')
        ->with('result_patients',json_encode($result_patients));
```

I used google charts that is why I sent my data as a json to the view, the data is then feed to the line chart of google chart.